# How to redirect to previous page? or How to get title from ForeignKey?

Tags: python, django

PART 1
I have some problems with redirecting on same page after click.
or example i was at /memes and after click i am at page /add_to_cart

OR PART 2
I have another solution for my problem

PART 1
in view i have

```py
def add_to_cart(request, **kwargs):
    return redirect(reverse('meme:meme_list'))
```

and my html looks like this

```html
a href="{% url 'shoppingcart:add_to_cart' post.id %}" class="col-2">
```

but if i am at the /videos and whant to add to cart i will be redirected at /meme. i ve found request.path_info but it only shows current path  (add_to_cart/1)

PART 2
I have category in my models for product

```
class product(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.PROTECT)

class Category(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=32)
```

so i can just make my prev path by '/'+ category title and i can't do it because

```
'ForwardManyToOneDescriptor' object has no attribute 'title'
```

how to get title from my category?

Answer (score 0):

```
request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER','/')
```

this how you get prev url page